# Python - merge two list of dictionaries adding values of repeated keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have two list of dictionaries which look like the following:

```
A = [{'id':'xyz', 'count': 3},{'id':'zzz', 'count': 1}]
B = [{'id':'xyz', 'count': 4}]
```

I want the final output to be like:

```
C = [{'id':'xyz', 'count': 7},{'id':'zzz', 'count': 1}]
```

So in case that if the value of the first key is the same in both lists, we add up the values for the second key. Any idea how I might achieve this? So far I have tried:

```
for elem in A:
    if elem['id'] in B.elementsKey['id']:
        # TO DO
```

I am stock where I am trying to update the value for the other element accordingly.

NOTE: Each id is unique.

Thanks

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Do the dictionaries have anything else in them? Might there be multiple entries with `'a': 'xyz'` in either list? Couldn't you just represent this as `A = {'xyz': 3, 'zzz': 1}`?

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Your question is currently to broad.

Comment: @ChristianDean alright modified it

Comment: I think you have the wrong data structure.  Why have a list of dictionaries containing key names `id` and `count`?  Why not just `A = {'xyz': 3, 'zzz': 1}`?  If you really need names include it in the variable name: `A_counts_by_id = {'xyz': 3, 'zzz': 1}`.  Then you're just a hop and a skip away from using `collections.Counter`, which is just a specialized dict that supports counts.  And you can add them together.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I would love to do that I have no control over these data structures as they are outputs of another existing function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

C_counts = Counter()
for l in (A, B):
    C_counts.update({x['id']: x['count'] for x in l})

C = [{'id':k, 'count':c} for (k, c) in C_counts.items()]
```

If you really don't want to import `collections.Counter` you can do:

```
_C = {}
for l in A, B:
    for d in l:
        _C[d['id']] = d['count'] + _C.get(d['id'], 0)

C = [{'id':k, 'count':c} for (k, c) in _C.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter('id')

lst = [{'id': k, 'count': sum(d['count'] for d in g)} 
                         for k, g in groupby(sorted(A+B, key=f), f)]
print(lst)
# [{'id': 'xyz', 'count': 7}, {'id': 'zzz', 'count': 1}]
```